# Spatial mean of vectors

Tags: math, vector, spatial, mean

I have a sample of vectors in the space (directions and norms). They represent the local spatial direction of movement on a surface. They are randomly distributed over the surface, but they represent a unique bigger vector flow.

As sample in the attached image the black vectors show the sample vectors and the pink vector shows somehow the center of the mass of the flow!

My question is I have a sample of vectors on the surface, how can I compute the center mass of the surface? I need its direction and its norm.

[image: Sample]

Comment: For a set of points you can find the center of mass https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass. I'm not sure how to extend this definition to vectors. I need the average spatial direction of the whole field and its norm!

Comment: You could treat each component separately and find the CoM for that, then combine to get a vector (CoM_x, CoM_y, CoM_z). Convert into magnitude and norm in the normal way. The main problem is that it won't necessarily mean anything, and you don't say what you want this value for - something else might be what you really want.

Comment: I don't see why you can't just add them all up (the vectors). This will give you the "average spatial direction". And the norm is then just the norm of that resulting vector.... Maybe you can be a bit more precise? Also, a sample with numbers might be more enlightening than a picture... Maybe you can tell me why my suggestion does not fit in your opinion...

Comment: The point is the sample vectors are not evenly distributed, but randomly.... So the simple mean would be biased!

Comment: Imagine we have a random sample of a vector field and I wanna find a vector representing the direction of field. I guess I need something like integration over vector field... ((?))

Comment: it must be related to curl of a vector field... I guess!

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit? Sorry, but like this it is very hard to understand what you are talking about. What you mean the vectors "are not evenly distributed" among what are they not evenly distributed. And when you say the "simple mean is biased", then biased towards what? Do you even notice that until this comment you never mentioned anything about the vectors being distributed randomly? How do you expect any useful answer if you don't mention this kind of stuff in the original question? Anyway, I suggest you move this question to math.stackexchange.com or mathoverflow.net/

Comment: In the question I mentioned few times I have a sample vectors of the surface. Even in the photo I put a random sample! And a sample is not certainly distribured evenly depending in the number of the sample! And when they are not randomly distribured then the mean would be biased to the direction of the sampled vectors but not the field!

Comment: What other information do you have about the flow? I mean, other than the sample? Or is this just a matter of getting a better sample? (one with less bias?)

Comment: How the heck is one supposed to see from a picture if something is 'random'? Moreover, if you don't know anything about your sampling distribution, how do you expect to be able to say *anything* meaningful. Either you forgot to mention information which is available or the problem is under-constrained. (Think of: 5 sample vectors. all point in the same direction, you can't conclude that this *is* the direction of the hole field. And you won't have the slightest idea of how biased you are). Also, how does "center-of-mass" relate to randomness? You have to tell us. Because this is not clear!

Comment: Any distribution has a mean (regardless of the type of the distribution), any set of points on the field have a mass point (regardless of how they are distributed n the field). All I want is to find a vector representing the mean direction on the whole field, assuming the vector field is smooth!

Comment: Omg. If I understand correctly: 1. There exists some unique vector flow. 2. you get some random vectors of that vector flow. 3. you want to use those random vectors to find the mean direction of the whole vector flow. Is this correct?

Comment: Btw. why don't you ask this question on either http://math.stackexchange.com/ or on http://mathoverflow.net/ ? (probably the first one of the two is more suited)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is basically the following:

There is a vector field `u(x, y)`. You have some samples `S` of this field. You then want to find the integral of the vector field over a finite region.

So the first thing you have to do is reconstruct the vector field. There are several ways you can do this. E.g. nearest neighbor interpolation, Voronoi interpolation, Shepard interpolation to name a few.

With this reconstruction, you can re-sample the vector field. Then, you can approximate the integral with a finite sum (Riemann sum).

Depending on your reconstruction method, there might even be an analytic solution, so you don't have to re-sample. I haven't checked, but this might be the case for Voronoi interpolation.

If you want to reconstruct points outside of the convex hull of your sample set, you should choose a reconstruction method that can also extrapolate. Though, be aware of the restrictions of extrapolation (i.e. there is mostly no real hint about the correct value).